# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when replacing constant literal value with constant variable

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering, what is a good way to fix the following compiler error?

```
class A {
    var x: Int32
    
    init() {
        x = -1
    }
}

let a: A? = nil

// No issue.
let ok: Int = Int(a?.x ?? -1)

// Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
let CONSTANT: Int = -1
let not_ok: Int = Int(a?.x ?? CONSTANT)
```

Any idea why we are getting *Type of expression is ambiguous without more context* if we use `CONSTANT` instead of `-1`?

What is a good way to fix the compiler error (retain same class, same type and same `CONSTANT`), yet still retain 1 liner?

Comment: I think if you change `let CONSTANT: Int = -1` -> `let constant: Int32 = -1` it will work. Another alternative is `let not_ok: Int = Int(a?.x ?? Int32(CONSTANT))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `??` operator is [declared](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L610) like this:

```
func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T)
    rethrows -> T
```

In the expression `Int(a?.x ?? -1)`, the compiler needs to infer `T` for the
`??` operator. It successfully infers `T == Int32`, because

- the expression `a?.x` has the type `Int32?`.
- it is okay for `??` to return `Int32` here, because `Int` has an initialiser that takes `Int32`.
- most relevantly, the literal `-1` can be converted to `Int32`, because `Int32` conforms to [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral).

If you instead do `Int(a?.x ?? CONSTANT)`, however, that last point wouldn't work. `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` only works with *literals*, not any constant. The compiler sees `CONSTANT` as an expression of type `Int`, and tries very hard to find a type for the expression `a?.x ?? CONSTANT`, but it can't, and spits out a not-so-useful error message.

I suppose the error message is not very useful because it needs to consider quite a lot of things in this case (return type, the two parameters, overload resolution for `Int.init`), and it could be rather hard to pinpoint exactly where went wrong.

Anyway, to fix this, you can just convert the constant to `Int32`:

```
Int(a?.x ?? Int32(CONSTANT))
```

Or if you don't want to convert `CONSTANT` to an `Int32` then back to `Int` again, you can rewrite this as:

```
a.map { Int($0.x) } ?? CONSTANT
```

"Map `a` to its `x` as an `Int` if `a` is not nil, otherwise `CONSTANT`".

Answer (score 2):

It's for the same reason that you can say this:

```
let d = 3.0
let d2 = d + 1
```

But not this:

```
let i = 1
let d3 = d + i
```

Swift will cast the literal `1` to the required numeric type (here, Double), but it won't cast a *variable* away from its type.

So the answer is: make the types match.